# Angular 4 Odata (ASP.net) Windows Authentication on Chrome

Tags: angular, windows-authentication, angular-http, angular-http-auth

I have an Angular 4 service that calls an OData API. I have my API setup to work using Windows Authentication, this works via IE (version 11) but not with Chrome, where it throws a:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

This is followed followed by:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gbldnrgaptest1:53219/User. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://gap' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I use the following methods to create my options for each request sent:

```js
private GetOptions(): RequestOptionsArgs{
    let options : RequestOptionsArgs;
    options = {
        headers : this.GetHeaders(),
        withCredentials: true
    };

    return options;
}

private GetHeaders(): Headers {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("OData-Version","4.0");
    headers.append("Content-Type","application/json;odata.metadata=minimal");
    headers.append("Accept","application/json");
    return headers;
}
```

On my API I have enabled CORS:

```cs
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "*")
    {
        SupportsCredentials = true
    };
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I have also enabled Windows authentication in web.config:

```xml
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
</system.web>
```

My IIS is also set to only allow Windows Auth:

[image]

Anyone know what may I be missing?

I feel like it's a header issue; as when I simply run a get request in Chrome e.g. by navigating to `http://gbldnrgaptest1:53219/User` it returns just fine, SOAP UI works too once I add in NTLM authentication.

Comment: Have u tried this http://www.leftycoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IISProvidersDialog.png

Comment: yes those providers have been available the whole time, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work, I had to do the following:

Add following to Web.Config:

```
<authorization>
  <allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*"/>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This was because the pre-flight request being sent out apparently does not send credentials, and this was causing the error to occur.
Now that the above rules are set **Anonymous Authentication** needs to be turned back on; the rule set in Web.Config will then filter what goes through, allowing only OPTIONS request to be done Anonymously.